# In Django, how to create a model that stores proposed changes to another model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, migration, django-3.0

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2.  I have the following model

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='CoopAddressTags')
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

We would like to set up a situation where someone could propose a change to a row in the db that would be reviewed before being saved, so I've created this struture

```
class CoopChange(Coop):
    """
    """
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
```

The problem is that when I create a migration, the table that is created simply points back to the original model, instead of storing all the fields

```
        Table "public.directory_coopchange"
   Column    |           Type           | Modifiers 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------
 coop_ptr_id | integer                  | not null
 created_at  | timestamp with time zone | not null
```

This is non-ideal because the original table would contain both finalized entries and those suggested for changes.  Is there a way to create an entity that stores proposed changes that mirrors the structure of the original entity?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of ways you could tackle this

1. Change `Coop` to an abstract base class:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Then you can inherit two classes from it `CoopProposed` and `CoopApplied` and you can work out what logic happens to create each

2. Just use the one class `Coop` and add a property called `approved` defaulted to `False` and then set it to `True` when you approve the changes.
   This might not be what you want as it will overwrite any previous changes and you might want to keep a history of changes.
3. Add a property `proposed` as a JSONField (check the docs if the DB you are using supports it) on the Coop class.  This can store a whole dictionary with the keys and values of the proposed changes.  When approved, the field can be read and applied to the model's properties in a function or something like that.

```py
class Coop():
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    ...
    proposed = models.JSONField("Proposed Changes", null=True)

    def apply_proposed_changes(self):
       proposed = self.proposed
       self.name = proposed.get('name')
       for type in proposed.get('types'):
           self.types.add(CoopType.objects.get(name=type))
       ...
```

In any case if you're trying to inherit all the properties from `Coop` you need to understand how Django model inheritance work and all the caveats before you get bitten later down the track:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: Thx but the second option doesn't work, unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion.  I want to record the current state of the Coop and the proposed change state.  If I don't accept the proposed change, I want to remember what the previous change was.

Comment: Ok yeah, then skip the second suggestion.

Comment: I've added a third proposed solution using a JSONField